# Why "String.prototype={}" won't work?

Tags: javascript, string, prototype-programming

I wrote this code in javascript:

```
String.prototype = {
  a : function() {
    alert('a');
  }
};

var s = "s";
s.a();
```

I expect it alert an `a`, but it reports:

```
s.a is not a function
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be replacing the *entire* `prototype` object for `String` with your object. I doubt that will even work, let alone be your intention.

The `prototype` property is not writable, so assignments to that property silently fail (*@Frédéric Hamidi*).

Using the regular syntax works, though:

```
String.prototype.a = function() {
  alert('a');
};

var s = "s";
s.a();
```

Comment: +1, the `prototype` property is not writable (`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(String, "prototype").writable` is `false`), so assignments to that property silently fail (but would noisily throw in strict mode).

Answer (score 4):

you have to write like :

```
String.prototype.a = function(){
alert("a");
};

var s = "s";
s.a();
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PNLxb/